# Any stopwatch app that can be embedded on my desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, widgets

I am looking for a stopwatch application that be embedded on my desktop like a widget but it doesn't ruin the over all look and feel of the desktop.

Comment: Is hours : minutes : seconds good or do you need more accuracy?